# Controller being pushed twice on iPad screen

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, navigation, segue

I am trying to segue to another controller by clicking on one of presented options on actionsheet. It works just fine on iPhone screens and it's being pushed to appropriate scenes, however issue occurs on iPad. I have been searching a lot for similar issue, but with no success.

```
@IBAction func actionSheet(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please select one of the options", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in }

    let recipeActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Get The Recipe", style: .default) { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GetRecipeID", sender: self) }

    let facebookActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Login with Facebook", style: .default) { action in self.handleCustomFacebookLogin() }

    //actions
    alert.addAction(cancelActionButton)
    alert.addAction(recipeActionButton)
    alert.addAction(facebookActionButton)

    // support ipad
    if let popoverController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = sender
        popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

***This approach is also not working:***

```
  let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Detail", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsVC") as! DetailsViewController
  let recipeActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Get The Recipe", style: .default, handler: { action in
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)})
```

I am getting this warning in console when pushing from iPhone:

```
pushViewController:animated: called on <UINavigationController 
0x7fd96a81f800> while an existing transition or presentation is 
occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

This is not showing when I trigger action from iPad, but new controller is stacked on top.[FirstController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb3lL.png),  [SecondController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmMu9.png)
 after clicking on getRecipe/Login button from previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to perform the segue from another operation

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation {   
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GetRecipeID", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do I need to put this inside action call?

Comment: Yes same position like before

Comment: { action in OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GetRecipeID", sender: nil) }}
This is not changing anything unfortunately.